# Selection not proper after rowspan on PrimeNG Table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am facing a strange issue. I am not able to select the merged row using rowspan on table of PrimeNG. Can anyone help me to quick fix this ?

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjfmib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)